# How to take pg dump from testing server to my pc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, pg, pg-dump

I am trying to take pg dump from testing server to my local machine, i have been logged into my server

root@myproject-staging-development1:~/myproject/current#

Which command should i write in here to get pg dump into my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dump Your PostgreSQL Database**

Step 1

SSH to the staging/production server.

Step 2

Dump the desired database:

```
pg_dump database_name > database_name_20160527.sql
```

You can name your dump as you wish - I'm using dates to distinguish multiple dumps.

Step 3

Leave SSH and download your new SQL file using SCP.

```
scp login@host:path_to_dir_with/database_name_20160527.sql database_name_20160527.sql
```

This command logs you into your remote server using SSH and downloads a given file to the local directory specified by you. If you give no path to the local directory, the dump will be saved in your current working dir.

Example:

```
scp marcin@8.8.8.8:/home/my_app/backups/my_app_database_20160527.sql my_app_database_20160527.sql
```

**Restore Your PostgreSQL Dump**

Step 1

If you want to use the current localhost database, you must drop it first:

```
psql template1 -c 'drop database database_name;'
```

Step 2

Create a new database on the localhost:

```
psql template1 -c 'create database database_name with owner your_user_name;
```

Step 3

And write your dump into the database:

```
psql database_name < database_name_20160527.sql
```

[Source](https://www.netguru.com/blog/how-to-dump-and-restore-postgresql-database)

Comment: I almost made it, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `pg_dump` via the `ssh` command so you have a one-liner:

```
filename="tmp/backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).sql"

ssh user@IP \
  "pg_dump --no-owner postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname" \
  >"$filename"
```